# Change the color depending on the normal direction

Tags: shaders, normals

I need to change the color of the cube surface depending on the normal direction.
For example, the surface of a cube should change color to red if its normal is directed upwards +/- 10 ° (on the Z axis).
Using shader editor of course.
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a *normal* output of the *texture coordinate*:

[image]

X is red, Y - green, Z - blue

This is in the local space. If you have to get in world space, use *vector transform* node:

[image]

Then you can use Separate XYZ and Map Range to get some effects:

[image]

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, if it should be within the range of +/-10° the _From Min_ value (and the _From Max_ accordingly) has to be much higher, around 0.985 (surely there exists a formula somewhere to get it more accurate). And if you want a gradual increase in strength, why not set the _From Max_ value to 1 to get the full range? If you just want to switch the strength between 0 and 1 I'd recommend adding a _Greater Than > 0_ node after the _Map Range_.

Answer (score 5):

The *Geometry > Normal* output returns the shading-point normal in World Space.

The *Math > Arccosine* of the *Dot-Produc*t of that vector with (0,0,1) will give you the angle between the shaded normal and world 'up', in radians.

[image]

Comment: +1 Ah, that's the formula I meant in my comment above. And using the _Geometry_ node instead of the _Texture Coordinate_ node makes this setup work universal no matter if you rotate the mesh in _Object Mode_ or _Edit Mode_ without the need for the _Vector Transform_. @arachnoden I actually would choose this as the better answer because it gives you the more accurate result where you can easily specify the +/-10° or any other angle you like.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Cranitzs ' answer is just fine, IMO, and it was there first :).  I wouldn't want to tread on its toes at all. This answer is more to your comment, above,  I guess, than to arachnoden.

Comment: Crantisz' answer is fine for sure, and I think having a gradient can be very useful which is easily done with his setup. But for the sake of the question where it says "change to red" and where is asked for a certain angle range I still think your answer gives the more accurate result. However, I don't mind his answer being accepted, why should I?  It's just my personal opinion or preference.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.